# Get substring position ignoring case sensitive

Tags: java

I need to get substring position in string while ignoring substring case sensitive. That means I hould like to get the same output result in case of:

```
String p = "aaaHelloddd";

System.out.println(p.indexOf("Hello"));
System.out.println(p.indexOf("hello"));
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Use `toLowerCase()`

```
System.out.println(p.toLowerCase().indexOf("Hello".toLowerCase()));
System.out.println(p.toLowerCase().indexOf("hello".toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: you may want to lower case your "Hello" then ;)

Comment: I give you a plus. Your answer is correct!

Answer (score -3):

You can simply change to uppercase and check for the uppercase substring.

```
String p = "aaaHelloddd";

System.out.println(p.toUpperCase().indexOf("HELLO"));
```

If Hello is a parameter simply make it uppercase.

```
String p = "aaaHelloddd";

System.out.println(p.toUpperCase().indexOf("hello".toUpperCase()));
System.out.println(p.toUpperCase().indexOf("Hello".toUpperCase()));
```

both prints the same results.

Comment: I don't understand the down flag. Can you explain?

Comment: I didn't downvote but it probably has to do with the fact that you answered a duplicate question. Some people see that as rep farming and downvote all the answers to those type of questions.

Comment: A downvote is not correct for a correct answer also if already answered!

Comment: repeating a same answer instead mark it as duplicate  is not correct either

Comment: If you copy and paste an answer yes. If you answer with a genuine answer without searching it and without knowing if it was already answered not!! Absolutely NOT!